# Create JOIN query in query builder to form doctrine symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, join, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm trying to create a join sentence which doing something similar to SQL sentence:

```
SELECT p.* FROM personal p INNER JOIN tematica_soporte ts ON ts.personalEmail = p.email ORDER BY ts.orden
```

I'm working with doctrine form in symfony, my current form is the next:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('consultanteemail', new ConsultanteType(), array ('label' => false))
        ->add('personalemail', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Personal de Soporte',
            'class' => 'GuiasDocentes\AppBundle\Entity\Personal',
            'property' => 'Enunciado',
            'by_reference' => 'false',
            'query_builder' => function(PersonalRepository $pr) {
                $query= $pr->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ;
                return $query;
            },
            'empty_value' => 'Elija una temática para su consulta:',
            ))
    ;
}
```

The issue is that I need order de objects 'p' by tematica_soporte.order. I'm beggin in doctrine I glad our help.

I believe that it should be something like this:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('consultanteemail', new ConsultanteType(), array ('label' => false))
        ->add('personalemail', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Personal de Soporte',
            'class' => 'GuiasDocentes\AppBundle\Entity\Personal',
            'property' => 'Enunciado',
            'by_reference' => 'false',
            'query_builder' => function(PersonalRepository $pr) {
                return $pr->getPersonalOrdered();
            },
            'empty_value' => 'Elija una temática para su consulta:',
            ))
    ;
}
```

**PersonalRepository.php**

```
    public function getPersonalOrdered(){
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->from('GuiasDocentesAppBundle:Personal', 'p')
        ->innerJoin('GuiasDocentesAppBundle:TematicaSoporte', 'ts')
        ->where('ts.personalemail = p.email')                
        ->orderBy("ts.order");
    return $query;
}
```

Nevertheless, it throw a strange error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 108: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got ','
```

These are the implicated entities:

Personal.php

```
class Personal{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
 */
private $nombre;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="apellidos", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $apellidos;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="departamento", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
 */
private $departamento;

/* Customized code */
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GuiasDocentes\AppBundle\Entity\TematicaSoporte", mappedBy="personalEmail")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */    
private $tematicasSoporte;

public function __constructor(){
    $this->tematicasSoporte = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->hilos = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function addTematicasSoporte(\GuiasDocentes\AppBundle\Entity\TematicaSoporte $tematicaSoporte){
    $this->tematicasSoporte[] = $tematicaSoporte;
    return $this;
}    

public function setTematicasSoporte(\GuiasDocentes\AppBundle\Entity\TematicaSoporte $tematicaSoporte){
    $this->tematicasSoporte[] = $tematicaSoporte;
    return $this;
}

public function getTematicasSoporte(){
    return $this->tematicasSoporte;
}
....
```

**TematicaSoporte.php**

```
class TematicaSoporte{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="enunciado", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $enunciado;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="orden", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $orden;

/**
 * @var \Personal
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Personal", inversedBy="tematicasSoporte", cascade={"ALL"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="personalEmail", referencedColumnName="email")
 * })
 */
private $personalEmail;
```

....

Comment: Actually, I'm trying with this:


`public function getPersonalOrdered(){
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->from('GuiasDocentesAppBundle:Personal', 'p')
            ->innerJoin('p.tematicasSoporte', 'ts')
            ->where('ts.personalemail = :email')                
            ->orderBy("ts.order");
        return $query;
    }`
But, it isn't work

Comment: Your `INNER JOIN` is missing its `ON` clause. Look up your relationships defined in your entity and modify the query accordingly.

Comment: Artamiel thx to reply. You could refer to something like this:
            `->innerJoin('GuiasDocentesAppBundle:TematicaSoporte', 'ts', 'ON', 'ts.personalemail = p.email')` 
Nevertheless, it have the same problem

Comment: You have to use WITH, not ON in querybuilder/doctrine. So it would be >innerJoin('GuiasDocentesAppBundle:TematicaSoporte', 'ts', 'WITH', 'ts.personalemail = p.email') - it should work fine then.